# Can I change the break in a bar chart in SSRS 2008R2?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Is there a way I can change when the bar chart is broken up?  I'm refering to the jagged line that shows a large difference between last value in order to save space.

Is there a way ssrs calculates this or a simple explanation of how ssrs breaks it up.

I'm getting small breaks in my chart and just wondering.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to configure where scale breaks occur in SSRS.

```
You cannot specify where to place a scale break on your chart. 
The chart uses its own calculations based on the values in your 
dataset to determine whether there is sufficient separation between 
data ranges to draw a scale break on the value axis (y-axis) at run time.
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220529.aspx

You can however configure the maximum number of scale breaks and there is a property called `CollapsibleSpaceThreshold` that can be changed to make the scale breaks less "aggressive".

Answer (score 1):

I know that the scale break is calculated at runtime, so you can not provide a static value. However, is it possible to retrieve that calculated scale break value at runtime, so I could use it in a textbox as a label.

For example, the scale break is calculated as 100.000 euro. If I could get this value I'm able to add the label "Attention: all values above 100.000 euro are using the upper scale break section"